# Loop orders in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables order_product, users and orders table, they all related each other and they work fine(as expected). I want to loop orders and not OrderProduct and also display them in the view . So far it is looping OrderProduct instead of Order, how can I loop orders and display in the view?

Here are the code.

Blade view

```
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
    <div>{{ presentPrice($order->billing_total) }}</div>
    @endforeach

    @foreach ($order->productInfo as $product)
   <div>{{ presentPrice($product->price) }}</div>
    @endforeach
```

User.php

```
  public function sellerOrders()
  {
  return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id');
  }
```

OrderProduct.php

```
   public function productInfo()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
 }

 public function orderInfo()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class,  'order_id');
 }
```

Order.php

```
   public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
  }

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity','total','Subtotal');
  }
```

Controller

```
   $orders = Auth::user()->sellerOrders()->with('productInfo','orderInfo')->get();
```

When I dd($orders) it shows this

```
  Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
  0 => OrderProduct {#300 ▶}
  1 => OrderProduct {#301 ▶}
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User class has the relationship defined with OrderProduct, not Order.

```
public function sellerOrders()
{
  return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id');
}
```

Comment: I know, but is there any way I can loop Order instead? I have tried to change OrderProduct to Order but everything went bad, that is why I have asked. @Jason Houle

Comment: What do you mean by "everything went bad"? I don't think anyone can really answer that without seeing the tables and their relationships.

Going by what you have already showed us you have the inverse relationship between Users and Orders.

        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'seller_id');

Answer (score 0):

`dd($order)` is returning what it should. Since the `sellerOrders()` relationship is with the `OrderProduct` table. You did eager load `order` with that call, though, so you should be able to just access that `one-to-one` directly on the blade.

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    <div>{{ presentPrice($order->orderInfo->billing_total) }}</div>
@endforeach

@foreach ($order as $product)
    <div>{{ presentPrice($product->productInfo->price) }}</div>
@endforeach
```

The above would get you what you're looking for.

Comment: This works for only `<div>{{ presentPrice($order->orderInfo->billing_total) }}</div> @foreach` but for the products it shows `Trying to get property of non-object` @N Mahurin

Comment: That would be because there is no `productInfo` model coming back from `$product->productInfo`. You're intermediate table is being used like a 3-way pivot table and I'm guessing not all orders have products.